# How to detect the current URL?

Tags: 6, uri

I would like to add a body class in D6 if you are on a specific page(s) currently in my `template.php` I have:

```
if url('the/path') {
 add the body class...
}
```

but that function doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: D7: [How do I get the full URL of the current page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27880/1908).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the following code, as `url()` returns the URL for the path passed as argument; therefore, it returns a value that the IF-statement would consider equivalent to `TRUE` (except in the case the string is `"0"` or is an empty string).

```
if ($_GET['q'] == 'the/internal/Drupal/path') {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: You might also need drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']) to check for source/destination path aliases.

Answer (score 12):

Drupal's Alias is what your looking for

```
<?php
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
if ($path == 'the/path') {
  // do stuff
}
?>
```

Others Below:

Full URL

```
<?php
global $base_root;
$base_root . request_uri()
?>
```

Drupal's "Internal" URL

```
<?php
$arg = arg();
// Path of 'node/234' -> $arg[0] == 'node' && $arg[1] == 234
?>
```

Comment: arg(); is the one for me. cheers ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Drupal 7**

```
// Retrieve an array which contains the path pieces.
$path_args = arg();

// Check if the current page is admin.
if (arg(0) == 'admin') {
  // This is wrong even in D7. path_is_admin() should be used instead.
}

// Conditionally add css or js in certain page.
function mymodule_page_build(&$page) {
  if (arg(0) == 'sth' && arg(1) == 'else') {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/my.css');
  }
}

// Load the current node.
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // This is wrong even in D7. menu_get_object() should be used instead.
}
```

**Drupal 8 (procedural)**

```
// Retrieve an array which contains the path pieces.
$path_args = explode('/', current_path());

// Check if the current page is admin.
if (\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject())) {
}

// Conditionally add css or js in certain page.
function mymodule_page_build(&$page) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'my.route') {
    $page['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/my.css';
  }
}

// Load the current node.
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node) {
}
```

**Drupal 8 (OOP)**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\AdminContext;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
class myClass {
  public function __construct(Request $request, AdminContext $admin_context, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->adminContext = $admin_context;
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  public function test() {
    // This might change in https://drupal.org/node/2239009
    $current_path = $this->request->attributes->get('_system_path');
    // Retrieve an array which contains the path pieces.
    $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);

    // Check if the current page is admin.
    if ($this->adminContext->isAdminRoute($this->routeMatch->getRouteObject())) {
    }

    // Load the current node.
    $node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node');
    if ($node) {
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [arg() is deprecated and will be removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705) at Drupal.org

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried request_uri()?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/6

Comment: Not sure what the  'best' way is, but this always worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the arg() function.  You can use it one of two ways,

```
$args = arg();
```

Which will basically give you an array with each url argument being another value, or you can check specific arguments like so:

```
$arg = arg(0);
```

So for your example, you could do:

```
if(!is_null(arg(1)) && arg(0) == 'the' && arg(1) == 'path') { Do something  }
```

or I'd recommend this:

```
$args = arg();
if(!empty($args[1]) && $args[0] == 'the' && $args[1] == 'path') { Do something  }
```

Comment: You could also use `$arg = implode('/',arg());`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have a different page template for pages with a specific URL, you can check the current URL using the following code.

```
if (arg(0) == 'the' && arg(1) == 'path') {
  // Add the extra CSS class.
}
```

[url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/6) is not the function that returns the URL of the current page; if you call `url()` without providing any parameters, you would get (at least on Drupal 7, and without any modules implementing `hook_ulr_outbound_alter()`) the base URL of the Drupal installation.
Calling `url('the/path')` will just return you `"the/path"`, if no module is altering the value returned from the function; that means that the code you have shown will always be executed, and the CSS class always added.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the canonical path that Drupal's serving a request for, you can hit $_GET['q'], which should translate even if Drupal's using clean URLs.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 8:**

arg() alternative since it no longer works:

```
$path_args = explode('/', current_path());
print $path_args[1];
```

Read more: https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705