# How do I get the full URL of the current page?

Tags: 7, uri

I need to get the full URL of the currently opened page. I use the following code, but it returns `http://localhost/mysite/page_name`.

```
$path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
$link = url($path, array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

It's not enough for my code to complete; I want to get the values that are passed with the URL as `http://localhost/mysite/page_name/value1=value&value2=value`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you tried using [request_uri()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/6)?

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . request_uri();
```

It should do the trick. I haven't tried it myself, and I may be off a bit, but I suggest you give a try.
From JavaScript, you could use the `window.location.href` variable.

Comment: great trick i used $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the url but the when i print the url:
sitename/pagename?field_empf_salaryfrom_tid=All&field_emp_date_value[value][year]=&field_emp_date_value[value][month]=  

How can i remove sitename/pagename

Comment: @abd You're probably looking for `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Can i Put every value from the url in a variable?  
Like 
the value of (field_empf_salaryfrom_tid=All) in $s

Comment: I suggest adding  protocol to the answer  with `isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https' : 'http';`

Comment: `request_uri()` even works on 404 pages, that's a really good thing.

Answer (score 32):

Here's how to get the absolute URL for the current page, using the Drupal API:

```
$current_url = url(current_path(), array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

If you need the extra (non-q) querystring parameters as well, you can use:

```
$current_url = url(current_path(), array(
  'absolute' => TRUE, 
  'query' => drupal_get_query_parameters(),
));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code.

```
global $base_root;
$current_url = $base_root . request_uri();
echo $current_url;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [$base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) variable, provides Drupal installation URL without "/" and [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) it returns path of current page being viewed.

```
global $base_url;
$current_path = $base_url . '/' . current_path();
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is pretty old but chiming in for people that might get there for a more recent version of Drupal.

You can get the current full-path for a page with:

```php
$path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$queryParams = \Drupal::request()->query->all();

$path . "?" . http_build_query($queryParams);
```

Really handy for dynamically changing the value of certain query parameters like a page for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is using url() API like this

```
url('your/drupal/path', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

Comment: The question is asking for a generic page, not one for which the path is known.

Comment: Ok, you can replace `your/drupal/path¡`with `current_path()`, as @david-thomas wrote before.